# What will be the difference?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, integers

> The average of 4 distinct prime numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ is $35$ where $a < b < c < d$. Given that $b$ and $c$ are equidistant from $34$ and; $a$ and $b$ are equidistant from $30$ and; $c$ and $d$ are equidistant from $40$; $a$ and $d$ are equidistant from $36$ . The difference between $a$ and $d$ is
>
> a) $30$  b) $14$  c) $21$  d) can't be determined.

My trial:
from given conditions:

$$\frac{a+b+c+d}{4}=35$$

$$a+b+c+d=140\tag1$$
$$b+c=2\cdot34=68 \tag2 $$
$$a+b=2\cdot30=60 \tag3 $$
$$c+d=2\cdot40=80 \tag4 $$
$$a+d=2\cdot36=72 \tag5 $$

Solving above equations I couldn't get the value of $d-a$.
Can somebody please help me solve this problem? My book says answer says answer is b) $14$ but I didn't get it.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, you know $30<b<34$ so there are aren't a lot of candidates for $b$...

Comment: You aren't using the fact that these are **prime numbers.**

Answer (score 1):

As lulu points out, $30 < b < 34$ and $b$ is a prime number, so $b = 31$.  Now, $a = 29$, $c = 37$ and $d = 43$, so $d - a = 43 - 29 = 14$.